# Implement MRU Algorithm

Tags: java, algorithm, caching

I want to implement a simple MRU cache: I'll use a queue:

```
get(Object):
```

- check if queue contains object

  - YES: remove it from queue and insert it at the beginning
  - No: forward request to system, get the element and insert at the beginning

Is this approach okay? I have seen that many implementations use Maps, but I don't understand why. Why do I need a Key,Value pair for a cache?!

Comment: you could add a `lastUsed` timestamp to your objects and sort your collection by that timestamp

Comment: forget about the MRU part (eviction could be a policy which can be plugged in). Think about the cache part. Would a queue make sense.?

Answer (score 0):

because checking if a collection contains an element is much quicker with a map (theoretically O(1)), with a queue you will have to iterate over all existing elements and compare i.e. O(sizeOfQueue)

Comment: Yes, but why would I use a Map and not a Set ?!

Comment: a set wouldn't allow you to retrieve the item from the collection, the Set API doesn't include a 'get()' function.